# Apply a filter to a single item of a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I would to implement a searching bar to my ListView.
I use a SimpleAdapter, the code is below:

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                        R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_LAT, KEY_LNG, KEY_IDLOC, KEY_DATE, KEY_IDPR}, new int[] {
                                R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost, R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude, R.id.id, R.id.date, R.id.pr});
```

I would apply a search bar only for the *KEY_ADDRESS* item. How can I do it?

EDIT: I add my Activity

```
 ListAdapter adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab3main);



    ParserTask pt=new ParserTask();
    pt.execute();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;

        try {
            menuItems = pt.get();
             adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                        R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_LAT, KEY_LNG, KEY_IDLOC, KEY_DATE, KEY_IDPR}, new int[] {
                                R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost, R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude, R.id.id, R.id.date, R.id.pr});

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried with:

```
final EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = myFilter.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                ((SimpleAdapter) adapter).getFilter().filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
```

But it return a NUllPointerException. Below Logcat:

```
  07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:689)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:813)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:43)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:54)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter$SimpleFilter.publishResults(SimpleAdapter.java:383)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-18 18:40:44.536: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: post your activity i'l help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write custom adapter for it .

Check this link - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: It return me a NullPointerException!

Comment: i added it! Hoping for a solution

Comment: Hello , there is no getFilter().filter(text) method in SimpleAdapter, please write a custom adapter, read the blog thoroughly .

Comment: And I can I do it in my own situation? Thanks

Comment: I know, but how can I do in my situation?